# Geotude vs. Lat/Lon

Tags: geolocation, geocoding

Does anyone have experience using [Geotude](http://www.geotude.com/about/nutshell)? I am looking for a fixed-sized area based earth grid system to use instead of the traditional Latitude/Longitude, so any comments or other types of grid would be super helpful!

Comment: I like this from their website : "Geotude is a solution looking for a problem :)"

Comment: Unfortunately, a Geotude is *not* fixed in size; the system is simply a different numbering scheme overlaid on the exiting lat/long system. Although each degree of latitude covers the same distance (they are concentric circles around the Earth's rotational axis), longitude is basically pie slices. Near the Equator the top edge and bottom edge of the slice are *nearly* the same length, but as you approach the poles, one edge goes to zero-length. So you only get equal areas for Geotudes at the same latitude.

Comment: I see. I'm trying to aggregate data into "sectors" and recombine these sectors when larger areas are required, hence the need for a fixed-area grid system. Any clue what could do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the bing Quadkeys? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx (scroll to middle of page)

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with R-Trees?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree

Comment: A bit, bit its not quite what I am looking for, as it only helps in finding nearby points, not finding which sector a point belongs to (unless I have a list of sectors of course)